# Launching previous state from resume() in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am facing an issue with my ionic2 application. The situation is when the app goes to back ground I save the last state in local storage, when the app resumes it check whether the value of lastState in local storage. If it has a value then that state is pushed. The error i am getting is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: <StateName>
at c (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13190)
at Object.reject (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:12546)
at NavControllerBase._fireError (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:44942:16)
at NavControllerBase._failed (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:44930:14)
at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:44985:59
at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8971)
at Object.onInvoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:4407:37)
at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8911)
at r.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:4140)
at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13731
```

But the application works fine. Could anyone please tell me the reason for this behaviour ?

### Code `app.component.ts`

```
     this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('[INFO] App Paused.');
            localStorage.setItem("lastState", this.nav.last().name);
     })
```

### resume() method

```
this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('[INFO] App resumed);           
            if(null != localStorage.getItem("lastState") && localStorage.getItem("lastState") != undefined) {
                this.nav.push(localStorage.getItem("lastState"));
            }
        });
```

NB: I have added all the component name in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case is you're trying to push a string instead of a imported module from the page, this'll only work if you're using Lazy Loading in your modules.
You have 2 options:

- Lazy load all your page components so you can use them on NavController as a string instead of the imported module name.
- Import all your pages, create an object with them and call `this.nav.push(this.yourCreatedObject[localStorage.getItem("lastState")]);` to access the parameter in your object that has the module (i don't even know if this will work, but it's worth a shot if you don't want to lose time lazy loading).

And just an observation:

When you enter on pause state the app'll remain on the page it was before pausing, there's no need to save the page and them pushing it again, when pausing it doesn't go to the root or loses the nav stack. And this could be bad for the UX since you'll be in a page and then push the same page again. So consider not doing this.

PS: There's a missing `'` in your console.log() on the resume method.

Hope this helps

### EDIT

So if you want the app to restart you don't need to push a page, you need to go to the root page of your application, so try `this.nav.popToRoot()`. This way you don't need to save the state or change to lazy loading.

### EDIT 2

Ok so restarting after 15min will require a counter and you to change your archteture to lazy loading.

You can do the following

```
public timer: any;
public counter: number = 0; // add these 2 variable to the scope of your class in app.components

this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("lastState", this.nav.last().name);
  this.timer = setInterval(()=>{
    this.counter += 50;
  }, 50);
});

this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
  const lastState = localStorage.getItem("lastState"); //GET THE LATEST STATE, YOU'LL ALWAYS HAVE ONE BE CAUSE THE APP'LL ALWAYS PAUSE
  clearInterval(this.timer); // CLEAR THE INTERVAL
  if(this.counter < 900000) // IF IT'S UNDER NEEDED TIME. 900000 == 15 min
    this.nav.setRoot(lastState);
  else
    this.nav.popToRoot();
});
```

This'll only work if the app is paused but not killed, if you want the same behaviour if the user kills and restart the app then you'll have a little more problems, like comparing when was the last time the user opened the app and if'ts under 15mins.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The reason for using localStorage is when the app is in background for around 10 to 15 mints, instead of resume it restarts. Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: @Dak got it, so i updated my answer. This is the only thing you need, did you managed to set a counter for the 10 ~ 15mints?

Comment: This will resume the app to the root page, not the sub pages right? My goal is to resume the app to the page when the app gone to background.I will check and will update you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your update. Your code works but I am getting the same error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:"

Comment: Have you lazy loaded your page modules?

Comment: Yeah, I got it. There was a small mistake in my code. Thanks brother for your time and help

Comment: @Dak your're welcome :) if this helped you please mark as correct so other ppl can find this. Thanks.